# Create table fails if foreign keys are used in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I seriously have no idea why this php code is not creating three tables. The first and second are fine. But the third fails. The third is very similar to the second but has another field after the foreign key definition. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$db = new \PDO("sqlite:d:/temp/test_db.sqlite");
$db->exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 'ON'");


$statement = $db->query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS customers(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
  name TEXT  
)");

$statement->execute();

$statement = $db->query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointments (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
  customer TEXT   , 
  FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(id)  
)");

$statement->execute();


$statement = $db->query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointment (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
  customer TEXT   , 
  FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(id),
  nextfield TEXT
)");

$statement->execute();
```

Comment: `customer TEXT` is the problem, I don't think you can say that the text in the column is ought to correspond to an int in another table. 2nd can pass because table already exists. 1) Do all 3 of them work if you clean up your db? 2) What's the error message you get?

Comment: 1) where do you see an INT?, 2) third doesn't work with a clean DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SQLite grammar](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) specification, `nextfield TEXT` should be placed together with the other column definitions. `FOREIGN KEY` relates to the `table-constraint` section and should be defined after column definitions:

```
$statement = $db->query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointment (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
  customer TEXT   , 
  nextfield TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(id)
)");
```

Comment: Ok. The foreign key documentation would benefit from a hint! https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 1):

FOREIGN KEY must be coded AFTER the columns, or alternately as part of the column definition without, FOREIGN KEY(column), as the column in implied, so replace

```
"CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointment (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
  customer TEXT   , 
  FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(id),
  nextfield TEXT
)"
```

with (table constraint):-

```
"CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointment (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
  customer TEXT   , 
  nextfield TEXT ,
  FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES customers(id))"
```

or with (column constraint):-

```
"CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS appointment (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
  customer TEXT  REFERENCES customers(id) , 
  nextfield TEXT)"
```

Comment: It is e.g. [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and ***This document does not contain a full description of the syntax used to create foreign key constraints in SQLite. This may be found as part of the documentation for the CREATE TABLE statement.*** In foreign keys part.